# How to call a function within a new function in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have created a function called `PV` which shows me `v_id` with lowest cost. Now I would like to call that function and would like SQL to display

```
p_name, p_description, QH associated
```

with this `v_id`. My question is how do I do that?

My tables are below along with my function code:

- Tb1: P (p_id (pk), p_name char (60), p_description varchar(300), qh (int)
- Tb2: vp (vp_id (pk), cost, p_id (fk), v_id (fk))
- TB3: V (v_id (pk), v_name)

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PV (@ptid AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vid AS INT
    DECLARE @min AS INT

    SELECT 
        ptid = VP.P_ID, @vid = VP.V_ID,
        @min = MIN(VP.COST)
    FROM 
        VPr
    GROUP BY 
        VP.P_ID, VP.V_ID
    HAVING 
        MIN(VP.COST) < 25

    RETURN @vid
END;
GO
```

**Note**: if I execute this function, along with my input for ptid as 9, it will return the correct `v_id`. To reiterate: I would like to call that function along with p_name, p_description, and qh

I am new to SQL functions. Kindly provide me an explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    p_name
    , p_description
    , qh
    , v_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            P.p_name
            , P.p_description
            , P.qh
            , vp.v_id
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vp.cost) R
        FROM
            P
            JOIN vp ON P.p_id = vp.p_id
        WHERE vp.v_id = dbo.PV(9) -- you may need to alter the schema from 'dbo'
    ) Q
WHERE R = 1
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on "you may need to alter the schema from 'dbo'"

Comment: If the function is stored in a different schema, e.g., rather than `DatabaseName.dbo.PV`, it might be `DatabaseName.Functionality.PV`, or something like that, in which case you'd specify `Functionality.PV`.

Comment: Thanks ! I have tried above code. But instead of displaying one v_id  result,above code is displaying two v_id results. I have one v_id INSERTED in two different p_name. Any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Comment: It's really a question of the logic you're looking to apply - which of the two rows do you want to display and why?

Comment: .I wud like to display second row because second row has my lowest vp.cost. currently SQL is displaying me both highest and lowest vp.cost

Comment: I've edited the query to take that into account; is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It works,but I was curious if there is another way to do it. perhaps view ?

Comment: It could probably be simplified, I just noticed you're passing a parameter, @ptid, to the function, but not using it?